# Regex.Replace rufuses to replace with newline

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I wrote a very simple C# program to use the C# Regex from command line instead of relying on the MS Word search and replace. The problem is that even though the Regex recognizes \r and \n fine, when I try to replace the string with either of these, it seems to replace it with the escaped character instead of the character itself.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string initial = Clipboard.GetText();
        Console.Write("Find: ");
        string find = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Replace: ");
        string replace = Console.ReadLine();
        string final = Regex.Replace(initial, find, replace);
        Clipboard.SetText(final);
    }
```

For example, my input string from the clipboard would be "Woodcock, american" (with a carriage return-newline at the end). the pattern would be @",.+\r", which matches fine, and the replacement string would be @"\r\n". This produces the string "Woodcock\r\n" (which are the letters r and n just to be clear). What am I doing wrong?

**edit:** Anirudh's answer solved my problem partially and I updated the code accordingly. However, it seems that when I input "\r\n" to the ReadLine it also escapes somehow, whereas if I write `string replace = "\r\n"` it actually replaces the string with a carriage return-newline. Link to new question : [C# ReadLine escapes carriage return/newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124590/c-sharp-readline-escapes-carriage-return-newline)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the verbatim "@" in so many places?  You only need it if you have a string that would be hard to read with escape characters or in places that you want to absolutely preserve whitespace.

Comment: Well it was just in case I had to use more complicated strings in the future, but on second thought it might be core confusing you are right.

Comment: @user2402806  readline is treating them as literals..replace \\n and \\r with \n and \r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are using verbatim string i.e `@""` which would escape \r\n treating them as literals and not special characters!

The replacement string should be `"\r\n"` **NOT** `@"\r\n"`

To solve your other problem

```
  Output=Regex.Replace(input,"\\r?\\n","\r\n");
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However this doesn't solve my problem since it only affects the match, which is working fine at the moment. So I still don't understand how to get around the ReadLine treating them as litterals.

Comment: @user2402806 read line would treat them as literals..use above code to replace those literals

Comment: Oh I see what you meant sorry. I added your code but it still doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.