# C# ReadLine escapes carriage return/newline?

Tags: c#, regex, readline

Hi I wrote a very simple C# program to use the C# Regex from command line instead of relying on the MS Word search and replace. The problem is that when I use "\r\n" as a replacement string in Regex.Replace *through Console.ReadLine()* it replaces with the th 4 characters "\r\n" instead of a real carriage return-newline. However, if I write `string replace= "\r\n"` it works as intended, i.e. replaces the string with a carriage return-newline. An Example input string would be "Woodcock, american" (followed by \r\n). As the code is it produces "Woodstock\r\n". Here is my code:

```
        [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string initial = Clipboard.GetText();
        Console.Write("Find: ");
        string find = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Replace: ");
        string replace = Console.ReadLine();
        string final = Regex.Replace(initial, find, replace);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Clipboard.SetText(final);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using Environment.NewLine instead of \r\n .

Comment: @Bearcat9425 That shouldn't make any difference

Comment: \ is not an escape character in the Console. If you want `"\\r"` to be `"\r"`, you need to do that replacement.  Escaping with \ is normal in C-like languages but not, for example, in VB. It would be weird for the Console to implement some language-specific style of escaping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex.Replace rufuses to replace with newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122859/regex-replace-rufuses-to-replace-with-newline)

Comment: @Bearcat925 I'm not sure what you mean by that. The problem is that the ReadLine seems to treat my input as litterals and I don't know how to get around that. I'm not sure where the Environment.NewLine would come in.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel That is my question which is marked as answered because it solved the initial problem.

Comment: If it doesn't solves your problem you shouldn't have marked it as answer

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel I marked it as answered but I realized too late that there was still a problem, so I assumed the question would not be visible anymore since no one had answered for a while after I unmarked the answer.

Comment: No, don't do that. If you do so people coming with same issues will think that accepepted answer is the answer for specific question. but actually not. Instead, edit your question for clarification, or just leave it as it is or delete it and ask a new one.

Comment: @mike z I realize it's not. ReadLine will interpret anything as litterals understandably, I just don't know how to get from that litteral string to the actual "\r\n".

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel Alright sorry; I can't delete the old question because it has answers, do you want me to delete this one?

Comment: No problem, keep in mind next time. Let's hope you get answer in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unescape `replace` (and possibly `find`), it should do what you need.

```
string initial = "Woodstock, American" + Environment.NewLine;
Console.Write("Find: ");
string find = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Replace: ");
string replace = Console.ReadLine();
replace = Regex.Unescape(replace);
string final = Regex.Replace(initial, find, replace);

Console.WriteLine("initial:{0}(BEGIN){0}{1}{0}(END){0}", Environment.NewLine, initial);
Console.WriteLine("final:{0}(BEGIN){0}{1}{0}(END){0}", Environment.NewLine, final);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Console I/O:

```
Find: Woodstock
Replace: Woodstock\r\n
initial:
(BEGIN)
Woodstock, American

(END)

final:
(BEGIN)
Woodstock
, American

(END)
```

[MSDN Regex.Unescape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)

Comment: Without good "given X, expecting Y" scenarios, it's kind of hard to fully understand what you're after.  This answer is, of course, a guess at what you actually mean.