# How to use escape character in a verbatim string?

Tags: c#, regex

Can I use escape characters like \r, \n etc in verbatim string for example

```
string pattern = @"(?<!</institution>\r\n)(?<!<institution-wrap>\r\n)<institution type";
```

Now if I try to do a search or search and replace using the **pattern** will it work or will \r\n be treated as a normal string?
How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern, yes, you can. See http://rextester.com/GHVMBZ97646 for an example. In a replacement, however, the backslash would be treated as a literal if you use a verbatim string, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122859/regex-replace-rufuses-to-replace-with-newline).

Comment: Then how do I do the replace??

Comment: If you want newlines in the replacement, either skip the `@` (as in `"replacement\r\nvalue"` rather than `@"replacement\r\nvalue"`) or literally have newlines in the source. Personally, I prefer the former as I find code (usually) harder to read when strings span multiple lines.